# How to insert multiple data in linked list

Tags: c

This program asks for two data ( a name and an id), and then stores them in a linked list and then it should output all the data one by one.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>


struct Test
{
  char name[16];
  int id;
};

typedef struct Node {
  struct Test structure;
  struct Node * next;

}TNode;
typedef TNodo* Node;

void NewDatainNode(struct Test  p, Node *pp)
{
  TNode *temp;

  temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  temp->structure = p;
  temp->next = NULL;

  *pp = temp;

}

void ReadData(struct Test * p)
{
  printf("\nName:");
  scanf(" %s", p->name);
  printf("\nID:");
  scanf(" %d", &p->id);
}


void ViewNodes(Node  node)
{
 while(node != NULL)
{
   printf("%s %d\n",node->structure.name, node->structure.id);
   node = node->next;
}

}

int Menu()
{
  int c;

  printf("\n\tM E N U ***\n"
     "1 - New\n"
     "2 - Print\n"
     "0 - Exit\n"
     "\n>> ");
   scanf(" %d", &c);

  return c;
}



int main()
{
  int c;
  struct Prova test;
struct Node * list = NULL;
  do {
    c = Menu();

    switch (c)
    {
      case 1:  ReadData(&test);
               NewDatainNode(test, &list);break;
      case 2:  ViewNodes(lista); break;
      default: c = 0;
    }

  } while (c != 0);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it outputs only the last data that has been inserted, what should i do to make it output all the data retrieved in function NuovaPrenotazione()?.

UPDATE: Now the function `NewDatainNodes()` looks like this:

```
void NewDatainNode(struct Test  p, Node *pp)
{
  TNode *temp;

  temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  temp->structure = p;
  temp->next = *pp;

  *pp = temp;

}
```

Thanks to Sandeep for the correction, the function works even without a return value,the problem was `temp->structure = NULL`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could translate the function names into English to make the code more understandable.

Comment: Max Langhof, here there is my previous version of the answer, i did some translation there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999982/parameters-of-linked-list-functions-called-in-switch-case

Comment: `scanf(" %s", p->nome);` has no width limit, as bad as `gets(p->nome);`.  Code should not use either.  Research `fgets()` and using width limits in `scanf()`.

Comment: Post rolled back.  Do not post answers in your question.   You can post your own answer below.  See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is exactly duplicate copy of a question posted yesterday and marked as duplicate. But, here is your working code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <limits.h>

struct Prova
{
  char nome[16];
  int id;
};

typedef struct Node {
  struct Prova struttura;
  struct Node * next;

}TNodo;
typedef TNodo* Nodo;

Nodo NuovaPrenotazione(struct Prova  p, Nodo pp)
{
  Nodo temp;

  temp = (Nodo)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  temp->struttura = p;
  temp->next = pp;

  pp = temp;
  return pp;
}

void LeggiPrenotazione(struct Prova * p)
{
  printf("\nNome Cliente:");
  scanf(" %s", p->nome);
  printf("\nID:");
  scanf(" %d", &p->id);
}

void Visualizza(struct Prova  p)
{
  printf("%s %d\n", p.nome, p.id);

}

void VisualizzaPrenotazione(Nodo  nodo)
{
 while(nodo != NULL)
{
   Visualizza(nodo->struttura);
   nodo = nodo->next;
}

}

int Menu()
{
  int scelta;

  printf("*** M E N U ***\n"
     "1 - New\n"
     "2 - Print\n"
     "0 - Esci\n"
     "Scelta --> ");
   scanf(" %d", &scelta);

  return scelta;
}



int main()
{
  int scelta;
  struct Prova test;
Nodo lista = NULL;
  do {
    scelta = Menu();

    switch (scelta)
    {
      case 1:  LeggiPrenotazione(&test);
           lista = NuovaPrenotazione(test, lista);
      break;
      case 2: VisualizzaPrenotazione(lista); break;
      default: scelta = 0;
    }

  } while (scelta != 0);

  return 0;
}
```

**Update**: Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Not sure what happened. I just copied above code, compiled and tested it. Got same result. BTW, i am using MS Visual Studio 2012 IDE for that. Which compiler you are using?

Comment: Minor: The `" "` before `"%d"` and  `"%s"` as in `scanf(" %d", &scelta);` is not needed.  `"%d"` and  `"%s"` consume leading white-space already.